# Text mining arabic & english with tm package in R - Issue with different results between MAC OSX and MICROSOFT Windows 8.1 OS

Tags: r, utf-8, arabic, text-mining, tm

## R - TM package - Issue with arabic - diff between Mac OS X and Windows OS

### ON MACBOOK PRO with RSTUDIO

````
```{r}
versionInfo()
```
1.R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)

2.Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

3.Packages : tm_0.6    NLP_0.1-3
````

### ON WINDOWS 8.1 with RSTUDIO

````
```{r}
versionInfo()
```
1.R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)

2.Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 

3.Packages : tm_0.6    NLP_0.1-3
````

### Problem description

Dear all,

I have been working all the week-end. I'm working on PhD on social network analysis. At this moment, I'm using TM package for text mining and analysis purposes, with english and arabic languages mixed in bid data sets.

The data sets are collected from Twitter API with a JAVA program and placed in a MongoDB data base.

For test purposes, I use a small dataset of 36000 tweets.

The problem is that for huge datasets computing (>1000000 rows), my MacBookPro would not be sufficient. I need to use a PC with Windows 8.1 OS which have better ROM and RAM.

When testing my Code on Windows 8.1 OS which working fine on RStudio on MAC OS X with the same test dataset, I have some different results from TM package at the Corpus compute level.

Here the beginning of the R code:

````
```{r}
y <<- dget("file") # get the file ext rated from MongoDB with rmongodb package
a <<- y$tweet_text # extract only the text of the tweets in the dataset
text_df <<- data.frame(a, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # Save as a data frame
myCorpus_df <<- Corpus(DataframeSource(text_df_2)) # Compute a Corpus from the data frame
```
````

When I check on R in MAC OS, all the character, english and arabic, are well represented :

````
```{r}
str(myCorpus_df[1:2])
```

List of 2
 $ 1:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "The CHRONICLE EYE  Ahrar al#Sham is clearly fighting #ISIS where its men storm some #Manbij buildings #Aleppo "
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2014-07-03 22:42:18"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "1"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"


 $ 2:List of 2
  ..$ content: chr "RT @######## جبهة النصرة مهاجرينها وأنصارها  مقراتها مكان آمن لكل من يخشى على نفسه الآذى "
  ..$ meta   :List of 7
  .. ..$ author       : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ datetimestamp: POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2014-07-03 22:42:18"
  .. ..$ description  : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ heading      : chr(0) 
  .. ..$ id           : chr "2"
  .. ..$ language     : chr "en"
  .. ..$ origin       : chr(0) 
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "TextDocumentMeta"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "PlainTextDocument" "TextDocument"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "VCorpus" "Corpus"
````

Nevertheless, when I do the same part of code in RSTUDIO on WINDOWS OS, all the arabic language is wrongly decoded (can't pass you here). the str of the Corpus show the same parameters. Only the display of arabic is unreadable. When checking at the data frame `text_df`, the arabic language is well displayed.

When I check the encoding of an arabic word on the both OS (MAC & WINDOWS OS), it seems to be well coded :

````
```{r}
Encoding("لمياه_و_الإصحا")
```

[1] "UTF-8"
````

I've tried to pass many additional information when creating the `Corpus` (with `readerControl`etc…) but nothing have changed : my arabic language is not well displayed in R or in RStudio on Windows OS with the tm package.

Is anyone have encountered the same difference issues between MAC OS X and WINDOWS OS with non-latin language text mining ?

Comment: I think the reason is that windows has different encoding than UTF-8. If you can, try use linux on that PC (eg via VirtualBox)

Comment: Yes I think the problem is coming from WINDOWS OS. The problem of virtualization is the loss of ROM/RAM efficiency on R text and data mining computations. I will try to follow on this way a few days and then find another solution.

Comment: Extract of the Corpus on Rstudio session on Windows 8.1 OS - look at the format of the text of the tweet of the second object):
{r} inspect(myCorpus_df[1:2]
``` <<VCorpus (documents: 2, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>
[[1]] <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>> The CHRONICLE EYE Ahrar al#Sham is clearly fighting #ISIS where its men storm some #Manbij buildings #Aleppo
[[2]] <<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>> RT @##### _1 Ø¬Ø¨Ù‡Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù†ØµØ±Ø© Ù…Ù‡Ø§Ø¬Ø±ÙŠÙ†Ù‡Ø§ ÙˆØ£Ù†ØµØ§Ø±Ù‡Ø§ Ù…Ù‚Ø±Ø§ØªÙ‡Ø§ Ù…ÙƒØ§Ù† Ø¢Ù…Ù† Ù„ÙƒÙ„ Ù…Ù† ÙŠØ®Ø´Ù‰ Ø¹Ù„Ù‰ Ù†ÙØ³Ù‡ Ø§Ù„Ø¢Ø°Ù‰ ```

Comment: Have you tried to change the default character encoding of windows 8.1?

Comment: I have downloaded some arabic languages packages for Windows 8.1. But it might be the display of arabic in R environment which is in cause: when you call the MongoDB database through rmongodb package and display the collections list, arabic names are in wrong format in R Console and R Global Environment. When you execute a data base collect from R to a data frame in R, the resulting R object display arabic in good format. But limitations of my R code with rmongodb do not allow me to build large data frames for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it seems to me that the Arabic characters are being encoded in some native (Windows-specific) encoding, while your `R` code is incorrectly decoding them as UTF8. That's why you're getting all those ennoying symbols such as "Ø" **. To verify this, just inspect the raw bytes of your string variables using `charToRaw` and then check the UTF8 character table.

I haven't worked with the `mongodb` package before, but I wonder if there is a way to force the data to be read from `mongodb` in UTF8 format, perhaps by specifying an encoding parameter of some "read" function.

** Actually, the reason I can immediately recognize those characters is because I ran into this kind of problem while working with Arabic tweets that I had obtained using the `twitteR` package.